# Resizing the image according to the parameters

Tags: javascript, express

So, recently I have decided to make an application which takes three parameters in its url: the width, the height and the url of an image. What it does is that it returns an image resized into the given width and height. And, indeed, I want it to be able to be used in normal programming as a src for an image to crop something quicker.
Could you give me any clues for ExpressJS?

Comment: Of course, I do "?" before the parameters: "?width=5?height=5" along with the url

Comment: What's the question? what have you tried and what result did you get?